# Cannot Install GNOME Tweaks on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome-tweaks

- I can't find the "GNOME Tweaks" app/tool using Ubuntu 20.04 Software app.
- I can't install GNOME Tweaks using terminal
- Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnome Tweaks is part of the "universe" repository, so you'll want to make sure that's enabled:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

From there, update `apt`:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then you can install Gnome Tweaks:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

From there, you can find it in your application menu:

[image: Gnome Tweaks]

Hope this helps.